# can I have intellisense when importing dart file in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

in VSCode, I can have intellisense like this, to help me find file question.dart

[image]

but in Android studio, I don't have that feature

[image]

it is just me or is it indeed not available in Android Studio?

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio, it seems I don't have to write `./`

[image]